# python - Scrape many URL's with Login in reasonable time

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, screen-scraping, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website where I need to be logged in to see the actual content. It all works fine but takes about 5 seconds per request which is way to slow for my needs (>5000 urls to scrape from). It seems there are faster ways like asyncio aiohttp modules.
However all examples I found on the web did not show how to login to a site and then use these tools.

So I basically need an easy to follow example how to do such a thing.

I tried to rebuild this example:
https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#what-is-concurrency 
with my code, which did not work. I also tried AsyncHTMLSession() from requests_html which returned something but did not seem to remember the login.

This is my code so far:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
"name" : "username",
"password" : "example_pass",
"destination" : "MAS_Management_UserConsole",
"loginType" : ""
}

links = [several urls]

### stuff with requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    c.get('http://boldsystems.org/')
    c.post('http://boldsystems.org/index.php/Login', data = payload)

def return_id(link):
    page = c.get(link).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find(id = 'processidLC').text

for link in links:
    print(return_id(link))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're already using `requests` so you can try [requests-async](https://github.com/encode/requests-async). The example below should help you with "*in reasonable time*" part of your question, just adjust `parse_html` function accordingly to search for your HTML tag. By default it will run 50 requests in parallel (`MAX_REQUESTS`) to not exhaust resources on your system (file descriptors etc.).

**Example:**

```
import asyncio
import requests_async as requests
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_async.exceptions import HTTPError, RequestException, Timeout


MAX_REQUESTS = 50
URLS = [
    'http://envato.com',
    'http://amazon.co.uk',
    'http://amazon.com',
    'http://facebook.com',
    'http://google.com',
    'http://google.fr',
    'http://google.es',
    'http://google.co.uk',
    'http://internet.org',
    'http://gmail.com',
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'http://github.com',
    'http://heroku.com',
    'http://djangoproject.com',
    'http://rubyonrails.org',
    'http://basecamp.com',
    'http://trello.com',
    'http://yiiframework.com',
    'http://shopify.com',
    'http://airbnb.com',
    'http://instagram.com',
    'http://snapchat.com',
    'http://youtube.com',
    'http://baidu.com',
    'http://yahoo.com',
    'http://live.com',
    'http://linkedin.com',
    'http://yandex.ru',
    'http://netflix.com',
    'http://wordpress.com',
    'http://bing.com',
]


class BaseException(Exception):
    pass


class HTTPRequestFailed(BaseException):
    pass


async def fetch(url, timeout=5):
    async with requests.Session() as session:
        try:
            resp = await session.get(url, timeout=timeout)
            resp.raise_for_status()
        except HTTPError:
            raise HTTPRequestFailed(f'Skipped: {resp.url} ({resp.status_code})')
        except Timeout:
            raise HTTPRequestFailed(f'Timeout: {url}')
        except RequestException as e:
            raise HTTPRequestFailed(e)
    return resp


async def parse_html(html):
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    if not html: print(html)
    title = bs.title.text.strip()
    return title if title else "Unknown"


async def run(sem, url):
    async with sem:
        start_t = time.time()
        resp = await fetch(url)
        title = await parse_html(resp.text)
        end_t = time.time()
        elapsed_t = end_t - start_t
        r_time = resp.elapsed.total_seconds()
        print(f'{url}, title: "{title}" (total: {elapsed_t:.2f}s, request: {r_time:.2f}s)')
        return resp


async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(MAX_REQUESTS)
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(run(sem, url)) for url in URLS]
    for f in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        try:
            result = await f
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**Output:**

```
# time python req.py 
http://google.com, title: "Google" (total: 0.69s, request: 0.58s)
http://yandex.ru, title: "Яндекс" (total: 2.01s, request: 1.65s)
http://github.com, title: "The world’s leading software development platform · GitHub" (total: 2.12s, request: 1.90s)
Timeout: http://yahoo.com
...

real    0m6.868s
user    0m3.723s
sys 0m0.524s
```

Now, this may still not help you with your logging issue. The HTML tag that you're looking for (or the entire web page) could be generated by JavaScript so you'll need tools like `requests-html` that is using a headless browser to read content rendered by JavaScript.

It's also possible that your login form is using CSRF protection, example with login to Django admin backend:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> get = s.get('http://localhost/admin/')
>>> csrftoken = get.cookies.get('csrftoken')
>>> payload = {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'abc123', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken, 'next': '/admin/'}
>>> post = s.post('http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/admin/', data=payload)
>>> post.status_code
200
```

We use session to perform a get request first, to get the token from the `csrftoken` cookie and then we login with two hidden form fields:

```
<form action="/admin/login/?next=/admin/" method="post" id="login-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="uqX4NIOkQRFkvQJ63oBr3oihhHwIEoCS9350fVRsQWyCrRub5llEqu1iMxIDWEem">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label class="required" for="id_username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" required="" id="id_username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label class="required" for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" required="" id="id_password">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/admin/">
  </div>
    <div class="submit-row">
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Note:** examples are using Python 3.7+

Comment: Thank you for the long answer. However this does not solve my problem. The point is that the login works fine, but the session then can not be reused for the async requests. If I request the pages without the login I'm just getting the login page as a response.

Comment: The session is open in the async call (not the other way around) and `requests.Session()` object allows to persist sessions and other parameters like cookies etc.

Comment: But shouldn't there be a session.post() somewhere in the fetch url function, to handle login before sending requests?

Comment: Yes, it should. This is just an example with a simple `GET` request but you should modify it according to your needs. I also provided the Django example with `POST` request for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Look at asyncio and using the asyncio.gather function.

Wrap everything below this "links = [several urls]" line in a method.

Be careful this is not thread safe, so don't change variables within the method.

Also this is threading so could be useful to use asyncio.sleep(randint(0,2)), to delay some of the threads, so its not firing all at the same time.

Then using asyncio call the below method with a new url like so

```
tasks =[]
for url in urls:
    tasks.append(wrapped_method(url))

results = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Hope that helps.

Otherwise look at https://github.com/jreese/aiomultiprocess

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried this but did not get it to work. Would you mind being a bit more precise about the actual code? Still not manage to login before using threading / asynio / aiomultiprocessing.